# how to measure the running time of a program in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

If I run a program ./a.out, and want to measure the time this program run. Is there such a command?

```
>> ./a.out
>> time xxxx
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time ./a.out` works on most Linux systems...

For more detail use:
`man time`

Comment: Note that there are multiple implementations of this tool: one is a bash shell buildin, while the other is standalone executable (which is more powerful).  This means that `man time` will show you manpage for GNU time and not for the bash buildin.

Answer (score 3):

```
SECONDS=0
run_your_program
echo $SECONDS
```

as an alternative to all the "time" suggestions bound to come up as answer.
SECONDS is initialised to 0 when shell starts, therefore you can also do calculations on before-after values, instead of initialising it to a specific value yourself. Useful as a kind of lap timer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command

```
$ time ./a.out
```